# Asymptotic behavior of system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to find the asymptotic behavior of the follow system of 100 differential equation:

$x'_i=x_{i-1}+x_{i+1}-2x_i, 1\leq i \leq 100\\
x_0 = x_{101}=0$

I'm trying to find the asymptotic behavior of this and am not sure of where  to even begin. I believe I need to find the growth and decay rates of the equations.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: Not yet, have you?

Comment: i have a guess but i'm not sure if it's correct. Have you done any of the others yet? I've only done 2 and a bit of 1 so far

Comment: Same with me. I'm working on 3 right now.

Comment: @johnson did you figure out the change of variable for 3 yet?

Comment: I haven't started 3 yet, did you do other ones yet? I figured out the answers for 1, but can't get it working on my notebook for some reason and I have 2 finished. Still trying to get something on 4 and I'll start 3 now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50086/discussion-between-johnson-and-drbistro240).