# How to solve this system of 100 differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$x'_i = x_{i-1} + x_{i+1} - 2x_i$ for $1 \le i \le 100$ given $x_{0}=x_{101}=0$

I've tried creating a matrix and dabbled with eigenvalues but have no idea what I'm doing with them.

So because it's a toeplitz matrix, i've gathered that I should have something like 1+ $cos(\frac{k*pi}{101}$)? is that the correct way to proceed?

Comment: I just edited it! sorry about that

Comment: Is this to do with numerics? Such as a finite difference scheme applied to an ODE or PDE?

Comment: What exactly do you want with these equations? An explicit expression for all components? Or a solution in terms of matrix exponential suffices? Do you have initial values for $x_i(t)$?

Comment: Just a tip - If you don't know how to do it with $100$ simultaneous equations, try an easier case (do it only for $2$ equations).  This strategy can be hugely useful in math.

Comment: This gives you a so-called _tridiagonal_ matrix that is also Toeplitz. This means there is a closed form for the eigenvalues, see [this wikipedia paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Eigenvalues).

Comment: @Mattos it looks like a numerical way to solve $\partial_t y = \Delta y$.

Comment: I'm new to this formatting sorry. I tried with just two, got $x_1 = x'_2 - x'_1$ but I'm not sure how useful that is. I believe this is a ODE @mattos

Comment: @TZakrevskiy That is what I thought originally, a second order central difference, except the RHS has no $(\Delta x)^{2}$ term in the denominator.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2057100/5531 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2055812/5531

Comment: Not interested in the asymptotic behavior, but more about the method. So I take it creating a triagonal matrix is the way to go at it?

Comment: @Mattos if you know how to solve $x' = Ax$, you can solve $x'=cAx$ for constant number $c$, just rescale your time variable. Maybe they omitted $(\Delta x)^2$ for simplicity.

Comment: as for the related links posted above, if the solution was 1+cos(k*pi/101) wouldn't the asymptotes be at y =2 and y = 0 for all x? or k in this case.

Comment: Hint: the eigenmodes has the form $x_k \propto \sin\left(\frac{\pi mk}{101}\right) \exp(\omega t)$ where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @achillehui how does that compare to the closed form a + 2sqrt(bc)cos(kpi/n) ? I haven't seen that form anywhere, trying to find a link about it.

Comment: No idea about your expression, but $\omega$ for the $m^{th}$ mode in above ansatz is $-2(1 - \cos\frac{\pi m}{101})$.

Comment: don't i just find the eigenvalues and then solve the matrix using the eigenvalue and calculating the determinant?

Comment: okay, I figure out what your closed form $a + 2\sqrt{bc}\cos(k\pi/n)$ refers to. If you substitute $(a,b,c,k,n) by (-2,1,1,m,101)$ in this closed form, you get the $\omega$ I mentioned above.

Comment: Is there a way to use matlab or any other scripting language to find an easier way to solve for the solution? 

Just to double check

Answer (score 1):

Compiling the hints of achille hui: Get your solution in form of a sine series,
$$
x_k(t)=\sum_{m=1}^{100}a_m(t)\sin\left(\pi·m·\frac{k}{101}\right)
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\dot x_k(t)
&=\sum_{m=1}^{100}\dot a_m(t)\sin\left(\pi·m·\frac{k}{101}\right)
\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{100}a_m(t)·2\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi·m}{101}\right)-1\right)·\sin\left(\pi·m·\frac{k}{101}\right)
\end{align}
so that
$$
\dot a_m(t)=-4\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi·m}{2·101}\right)·a_m(t)
$$
is a decoupled system.

You get the coefficients $a_m(0)$ for the initial state either by a sine transformation formula or by the Fourier transform after you extend the points by $x_{-k}(0)=-x_k(0)$ to the index set $[-101, 100]$ to a periodic sequence with period $202$.